# Display Google AdSense ads to search engine visitor only

Tags: javascript, html, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm using below blogger/weebly code for Displaying AdSense Ads only for search engine visitor.
But Code not working...
Ads not showing...
Whats wrong with this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer.match(/google|yahoo|bing|altavista|digg/)) {

google_ad_client = "xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
/* xxxxxxxx xxxxxx xxx xxx xxx xx xxxxxx */
google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
google_ad_width = xxx;
google_ad_height = xxx;

var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", src);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
} else {
// Show something to visitors not referred by a search engine
}
</script>
```

Please Help me, Sir. Thanks.

Comment: why did you tag this `php` ??

Comment: i am sorry for tag php. i edited it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", src); // this is your problem. src variable doesn't exist
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

This code is correct. It adds a `script` element to the `head`. The problem is the `src` variable is not defined anywhere.

Comment: script.setAttribute("src", src); // this is your problem. src variable doesn't exist

Comment: I'm not saying that you have to place that code. That code is yours, and I'm just telling you that those 3 lines you have are correct. They work as expected. The problem is that you are using a variable called `src` which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: What's the value of the `src` variable? Can you tell us?

Comment: can i change variable `src` ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what that part of the code is doing. Is trying to create an element like this `<script src="url_to_js_file.js"></script>` and then add that element into `<head></head>`. So, if instead of `src` you put any string ("foo"), you will see how it's working correctly. Inspect the webpage and look at what's inside the head. The question here is, what's the value of the `src` variable?

Answer (score 0):

I think what the others have pointed out is that **src** is not defined in script.setAttribute("src", src);, and it is causing the issue.

This:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.setAttribute("src", src);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

Should be:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
var src ="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
script.setAttribute("src", src);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

~

Depending on where you want the code to be displayed, seeing that you are using Weebly, you could just add the code to an Embed Code Element somewhere in the content area. (no need to be appending anything to the head).

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (document.referrer.match(/google|yahoo|bing|altavista|digg/)) {
    //your javascript
    alert("referred by a search engine");
} else {
    alert("Show something to visitors not referred by a search engine");
}
</script>
```